# Creating a thunk with arguments. Getting "Parameter 'dispatch' implicitly has an 'any' type"

Tags: typescript, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm pretty new with redux-thunk and particularly with the added complexity of Typescript. This is probably unneeded information but just in case what I'm trying to do is define a thunk to handle all API requests. To do this I need to have an Id to handle the state of each request.
The code would be something like this:

```
export const createRequest: apiRequestActionCreator = (requestId: string) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
//do stuff
dispatch(requestStartedAction(requestId));
try {
    //do stuff
    dispatch(requestSucceededAction(requestId));
} catch (error) {
    //do stuff
    dispatch(requestFailedAction(requestId, error));
}
```

And apiRequestActionCreator is a function that returns a ThunkAction like this:

```
export type apiRequestActionCreator = () => ThunkAction<void, apiRequestStates, {}, apiRequestAction>
```

As soon as I add the requestId argument to the thunk I get the error `Parameter 'dispatch' implicitly has an 'any' type`. (I get no error with an no argument function)

I have to assume there's a way to do this but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem as well (this is my first time answering on stack overflow so yeah)  but what i did was to this `return async (dispatch: any)` and seems to work fine afterwards

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
export const createRequest: apiRequestActionCreator = (requestId: string) =>
 async (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<State, unknown, Actions>, getState) =>
{
...
}
```

With `State = apiRequestStates` and `Actions = apiRequestAction`